# Sort AlphaNumeric versions

Tags: apex, string, sort

How to sort the Version(i.e) `'1.4.7','5.19.0','5.18.0','5.14.1','5.8.1','5.8.2','5.20.1','5.20.0'` something like this. Initially tried with splitting by DOT and then comparing the First value in a list and second and so on, which worked totally fine or using bubble sort.

But then Requirement changed and sorting Input is AlphaNumneric

```
{'1.4.7','5.14.2', '8.2.alpha', '9.beta', 'other'}
```

Which I changed to an integer by using string CharAt. But it fails at some test cases as 5.14.1 value is around 100+ and 5.20.1 value is less than 100 and it's wrong.

```
b = b + integer.valueOf(val.charAt(k));
```

Saw **Apex CompareTo** Not sure if it will work in my case or No idea How it works.

**`Will it works for my requirement`**
and please provide the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend create separate class for version which implements [Comparable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm)

```java
global class VersionNumber implements Comparable {
    private String versionName;
    private String major;
    private String minor;
    private String build;

    public VersionNumber(String versionName) {
        this.versionName = versionName;
        parse();
    }

    private void parse() {
        List<String> tokens = this.versionName.split('\\.');
        System.debug(tokens);
        this.major = tokens[0];
        this.minor = tokens.size() >= 2 ? tokens[1] : '';
        this.build = tokens.size() > 2 ? tokens[2] : '';
    }

    // Implement the compareTo() method
    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        VersionNumber compareToVersionNumber = (VersionNumber)compareTo;
        if (this.major == compareToVersionNumber.major
                && this.minor == compareToVersionNumber.minor
                && this.build == compareToVersionNumber.build) {
            return 0;
        }
        Integer compResult = compare(this.major, compareToVersionNumber.major);
        if (compResult != 0) {
            return compResult;
        }
        compResult = compare(this.minor, compareToVersionNumber.minor);
        if (compResult != 0) {
            return compResult;
        }
        return compare(this.build, compareToVersionNumber.build);
    }

    private Integer compare(Object a, Object b) {
        if (a == null) {
            return -1;
        }
        if(b == null){
            return 1;
        }
        if (a instanceof Integer) {
            if (b instanceof Integer) {
                Integer intA = Integer.valueOf(a);
                Integer intB = Integer.valueOf(b);
                Integer aSubB = intA - intB;
                return aSubB > 0 ? 1 : (aSubB == 0 ? 0 : -1);
            }
            return -1; // Integer < String
        }
        if (b instanceof String) {
            return ((String) a).compareTo((String) b);
        }
        return 1; // String > Integer
    }
}
```

Testing:

```java
List<VersionNumber> versions = new List<VersionNumber> {
        new VersionNumber('other'),
        new VersionNumber('1.4.7'),
        new VersionNumber('9.beta'),
        new VersionNumber('5.14.2'),
        new VersionNumber('8.2.alpha')
};
versions.sort();
System.debug(versions);
```

Answer (score -1):

Below `sort` will work for array consisting of alphanumberic numbers. You can use it as a way to implement sort for including dots.

```
var points = [40, 100, "2rt", "other", "asd", "12wer", 1, 5, 25, 10,];

    points.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (((typeof a) === 'number') && ((typeof b) === 'number'))
            return (a - b);
        else if (((typeof a) === 'number') && ((typeof b) !== 'number'))
            return -1;
        else if (((typeof a) !== 'number') && ((typeof b) === 'number'))
            return 1;
        else {
            if (parseInt(a) && parseInt(b)) return (parseInt(a) - parseInt(b));
            else if (parseInt(a) && !parseInt(b)) return -1;
            else if (!parseInt(a) && parseInt(b)) return 1;
            return -1;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What would this look like (roughly) in Apex?